# @font-face legality issues

Tags: css, font-face

I've just heard of the @font-face CSS attribute, and I was wondering if there any legality issues.

I have heard that only certain fonts can be embedded?  What about completely custom ones, like a Super Mario Bros. font?  Is that legal to embed?

Just wondering..

Comment: By legality do you mean concerning font copyright?

Comment: As long as that is the only legal issues concerning fonts, then yes! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are legally allowed in the font license to either redistibute the font and/or only redestribute in the usage of @font-face. IANAL and this is not legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the license mentions that web-embedding is allowed. SIL OPEN Fonts are web-embeddable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://typekit.com/ for legal type faces you can embed